# Why is the magnitude of a complex number defined using complex conjugate?

Tags: complex-numbers, inner-products

Why is the notion of magnitude of a complex number ,$a = x+iy$ , defined as $|a|^2 = \bar{a}a$ ?

Should I think of the conjugate as the dual space and it is used to define an inner product where we can define a notion of length? I am unsure if this is the correct interpretation.

Please feel free to refer me to a text that covers this with some rigor.

Answer (score 1):

An algebraic/geometric view: Consider the representation of a complex number $z = a + ib$ on the complex plane. By Pythagoras' theorem, its length is given by $|z|^2 = a^2 + b^2$. By some calculations, $z \overline{z} = (a + ib)(a - ib) = a^2 + b^2$, so $|z|^2 = z \overline{z}$.

Another point of view is that $\langle z, w \rangle = \overline{z} w$ defines an inner product on $\mathbb{C}$, and so the norm given by $\langle z, z \rangle = \overline{z} z$ is a reasonable notion of length. Note that this agrees with the more elementary view given above, and that it also generalises well to norms on $\mathbb{C}^n$ given by $\langle x, y \rangle = x^*y$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: I see, so it is to define the notion of an inner product on $\mathbb{C}$. Does this mean that the complex conjugates belong to a dual space? or does the notion of dual space not exist for fields?

Comment: What do you mean by a dual space exactly?

Comment: Such as the bras are duals to the kets. As in the bras are a set of linear functionals/maps that take elements from the ket space to complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, if you view $V = \mathbb{C}^n$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ then the complex conjugate naturally lives in the dual space $V^*$ too. For $z^* \in V^*$, we have the linear form $z^* : V \to \mathbb{C}, w \mapsto z^* w$. (The case $n = 1$ corresponds to what you are considering.) Personally, I'm not sure if this best motivates the definition of length though.

Comment: Can you provide a better motivation for the definition of length ?

Comment: The simple geometric one I described in the answer?